# Web scraping for divs inserted by scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2, urllib

Sorry if this is a silly question.

I am trying to use Beautifulsoup and urllib2 in python to look at a url and extract all divs with a particular class. However, the result is always empty even though I can see the divs when I "inspect element" in chrome's developer tools.

I looked at the page source and those divs were not there which means they were inserted by a script. So my question is how can i look for those divs (using their class name) using Beautifulsoup? I want to eventually read and follow hrefs under those divs.

Thanks.

[Edit]
I am currently looking at the H&M website: http://www.hm.com/sg/products/ladies and I am interested to get all the divs with class '*product-list-item*'

Comment: Can you post the url you try to scrape to check if it use javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try using selenium to run the javascript

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
html = driver.page_source
```

Answer (score 0):

check this link [enter link description here](http://api.hm.com/v2/sg/en/products/display?categories=ladies&concealCategories=true&pageSize=60&page=1)

you can get all info by change the url, this link can be found in chrome dev tools > Network

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you got nothing from that specific url is simply because, **the info you need is not there**.

So first let me explain a little bit about how that page is loaded in a browser: when you request for that page(http://www.hm.com/sg/products/ladies), the literal content will be returned in the very first phase(which is what you got from your urllib2 request), then the browser starts to read/parse the content, basically it tells the browser where to find all information it needs to render the whole page(e.g. CSS to control layout, additional javascript/urls/pages to populate certain area etc.), and the browser does all that **behind the scene**. When you "inspect element" in chrome, the page is already fully loaded, and those info you want is not in original url, so you need to find out which url is used to populate those area and go after that specific url instead.

So now we need to find out what happens behind the scene, and a tool is needed to capture all traffic when that page loads(I would recommend [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)).

[image: traffic captured by fiddler]

As you can see, lots of things happen when you open that page in a browser!(and that's only part of the whole page-loading process) So by educated guess, those info you need should be in one of those three "api.hm.com" requests, and the best part is they are alread JSON formatted, which means you might not even bother with BeautifulSoup, the built-in `json` module could do the job!

OK, now what? Use `urllib2` to simulate those requests and get what you want.

P.S. `requests` is a great tool for this kind of job, you can get it [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Answer (score 0):

Try This one :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.hm.com/sg/products/ladies")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(),'lxml')

scrapdiv = open('scrapdiv.txt','w')

product_lists = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"o-product-list"})
print product_lists
for product_list in product_lists:
    print product_list
    scrapdiv.write(str(product_list))
    scrapdiv.write("\n\n")
scrapdiv.close()
```